# Using MySQL to Generate SHA-256 Hashes?

Tags: mysql

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hashes (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  text varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  hash varchar(64) NOT NULL AS (SHA2(CONCAT(text), 256) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And then I want to run an insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO `hashes` (`text`) VALUES ('testing');
```

From the research I've done, the `id` should be automatically generated since `auto_increment` is enabled, so I don't need to define it in the insert query.

From my `CREATE TABLE` query, the `hash` should be automatically generated based upon the data entered into the `text` field.  However, when I run the `CREATE TABLE` command I get an error with this line:

`hash varchar(64) NOT NULL AS (SHA2(CONCAT(text), 256) STORED`

I'm just wanting the `hash` to be automatically generated similar to how `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will automatically generate the current time by default.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "Automatically display"? A table holds data, that's all it does. You would have to write to `text` table and then also write to the `hashes` table with the hash of whatever you wrote into the `text` table. Later on you can join the two tables to display the `text` and the hash. Also... why store the `hash` in it's own table?

Comment: Well actually I guess it doens't matter what table the hashes are stored in.  They can be stored in the same table.  But, what I'm trying to prevent if having to create the hashes or having to insert them.  Basically I just want to insert the text and then have MySQL generate the hash for that text.

Comment: I just updated the question to include examples of exactly what's happening.  Thanks!

Comment: I believe you'll need a trigger to pull that off like `create trigger add_sha2 before insert on hashes for each row
begin set new.hash = SHA2(text, 256);` or similar. Of course that comes with it's own caveats since now you have to maintain both a table and a trigger for that table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have syntax error. You should write `NOT NULL` after `SHA2` hash function. Please try:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hashes (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  text varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  hash varchar(64) AS (SHA2(CONCAT(text), 256)) STORED  NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `hashes` (`text`) VALUES ('testing');
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare your `hash` column as NOT NULL. It's based on another NOT NULL column, `text`, so the hash will naturally be NOT NULL as well.

You also have forgotten a closing parenthesis.

```
hash varchar(64) AS (SHA2(CONCAT(text), 256)   STORED,
                    1    2      3    3     2 ^
```

You need another closing paren where I indicated `^`.

Answer (score 1):

If you **already have the table filled by some content**, you can Alter it with :

```
ALTER TABLE `page` ADD COLUMN `hash` char(64) AS (SHA2(`content`, 256)) AFTER `content`
```

This solution will add `hash` column right after the `content` one, make hash for **existing and new records** too. Unique index can be added to prevent insertion of large content duplicates.