# How to hash during create table and insert in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table that has a column that hashes the `id` (not unique), the `word` and the the boolean on datetime `valid`. How can I hash int, string and boolean and then store it into table if it does not exist?

I have divided the problem into several step but I cant seem to put it all together:

I know how to hash:

```
SELECT crc32(concat(id, word, boolean)) FROM testhash;
```

Here is how I can check if the date is valid:

```
SELECT id FROM testhash WHERE valid > NOW();
```

Then I can insert the hash into table if it does not exist:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO testhash (word,valid,hash) VALUES ('testword', STR_TO_DATE("2022-07-10", "%Y-%m-%d"), 'hereisthehash');
```

Here is how I try to create a table but it does not work:

```
CREATE TABLE testhash (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  word varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  valid datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  hash varchar(64) AS (crc32(CONCAT(id, word))) STORED NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Tried to sqlfiddle but that failed too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/297837

During my attempt I tried to replicate the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53619069/6130540

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5903729/6130540

Comment: `AS (crc32(id) ...` <-- you seem to be missing a closing parenthesis here.

Comment: since valid is nondeterministic (it will change over time), you can't use a unique key for this.

Comment: for the other parts, why use a hash instead of just a key on (id,word)?